# I want to retrieve all channel name that I subscribing now.

Tags: redis

I've have subscribe multiple channels at a time. 
I want to retrieve all channel name that I subscribing now.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Redis does not return this list. But you can maintain it by yourself. Each time you subscribe, you can add the channel to a set. Each time you unsubscribe, you remove the channel from the set.

There is no need to do something on server-side, when it can easily be done on client-side.

Comment: Okay, I'll do it myself. Thank you.